# set variable only if another variable exists in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a shorter way to do this in ruby?

```rb
if defined? some_var
    other_var = some_var
end
```

Set `other_var` with the value of `some_var` if and only if `some_var` exists, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: what happened with @CDub's answer?

Comment: I removed it due to the fact that if `some_var` was not defined, it would throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

```
other_var = some_var if defined? some_var
```

Comment: I think this is more easily to understand

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter!

```
defined?(some_var) && other_var = some_var
```